# Bamboo remote agent pool

Tags: bamboo

In Jenkins, we can define labels and group number of build slaves under the label. This label then can be mapped to job so jenkins will automatically pick the available build slaves in the pool and execute the jobs. Is something similar available in bamboo to create remote agent pool?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly but anyway... There's similar concept in Bamboo. There are two types of agents:

- Local ones which operate as a thread in Bamboo server. Generally, not recommended for bigger Bamboo instances due to performance and security reasons.
- Remote ones which are basically separate processes running the builds, ideally on a different machine so Bamboo server doesn't suffer from higher hardware load.

The match between job and agents bases on job requirement and agent capabilities, e.g:

- Agent define a capability, effectively states what it can build, what tools are installed, e.g. .NET or JDK
- Job/deployment environment define a requirement which is need to successfully accomplish the task, e.g. Git and Maven.

In the end Bamboo tries to find an agent which provides full set of capabilities a job/deployment environment requires.

The special rules applies if an agent is dedicated to an job or environment or agent is elastic agent (runs in EC2).

More reading:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/difference-between-local-agents-and-remote-agents-457703602.html
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-a-job-s-requirements-289277064.html
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-a-job-s-requirements-289277064.html
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/requirements-for-deployment-environments-838427584.html
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/dedicating-an-agent-629015108.html
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/managing-your-elastic-image-configurations-289277147.html